# QBO unable to upload invoice

Tags: quickbooks, invoice

My task is to upload an invoice to UK QuickBooks Online.

I always get an error:
"You must select a product/service or an account for each split line with either an amount or a billable $$customer$$."

My XML request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Invoice xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2" xmlns:ns2="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbopayroll/v1" xmlns:ns3="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo">
<Header>
    <TxnDate>2013-11-30</TxnDate>
    <CustomerId idDomain="QBO">1</CustomerId>
    <TaxAmt>6.8</TaxAmt>
    <BillAddr>
        <Line1>Alex</Line1>
        <Line2>Test</Line2>
        <Line3>Prague</Line3>
    </BillAddr>
    <ShipAddr>
        <Line1>Test</Line1>
        <Line2>Prague</Line2>
    </ShipAddr>
    <BillEmail></BillEmail>
    <DiscountTaxable>false</DiscountTaxable>
</Header>
<Line>
    <Desc>Internet connection</Desc>
    <Amount>34</Amount>
    <Taxable>true</Taxable>
    <ItemId>3</ItemId>
    <UnitPrice>34</UnitPrice>
    <Qty>1.00</Qty>
</Line>
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the v2 APIs, which *only support the USA QuickBooks Online* editions.

Have you tried using [the v3 APIs](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/invoice), which use a [global tax model](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/020_key_concepts/global_tax_model) which supports what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks, Keith. Couldn't find any documentation about UK support. v2 doing something really weird. It can retrieve data from UK quickbooks, but can't upload it.

My task is just retrieve customers FROM QB and upload invoices to QB. Is it possible in v3?

Comment: And one more thing. Should I use QBXML instead of REST api V3 for QBD?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For QBD, you should use qbXML. For QBO, you should use the v3 APIs. You should never be using v2 anymore.